# Where do attr_reader, attr_writer, attr_accessor methods exist? How are they implemented?

Tags: ruby

I want to know where three methods `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor` exist. Here,

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title, :price
  def initialize(title, price)
    @title = title
    @price = price
  end
end

book1 = Book.new("Ruby essentials", 100)
puts book1.title
puts book1.price
```

I am calling `attr_reader`. I want to know its implementation hints too. Anyone please describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are implemented in `Module`. See [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader).

MRI's implementation in C is e.g. for `attr_reader`:

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_attr_reader(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        rb_attr(klass, id_for_attr(argv[i]), TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

Since `Class` is a child of `Module`, they are available in each class definition.

Comment: I want know implementation of those methods in ruby library not ruby compiler source code.

Comment: @FarukHossen: This ***is*** the implementation of the Ruby "library" (for MRI). The Ruby interpreter including all core classes is implemented in C. There exists no Ruby compiler.

Comment: @FarukHossen The implementation is in C code: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/20690026a7dd7622c7d824de71e337a68a293b63/object.c#L1938-L2020

Answer (score 3):

`attr_reader` and `attr_writer` are methods implemented in `Module`. Those methods create some other methods for you. `attr_reader` method create a getter method whereas `attr_writer` create a setter method. `attr_accessor` method called `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`

Both `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` accept multiple arguments.

The implementation is like that

```
class Module
    def my_accessor(*args)
        my_reader(*args)
        my_writer(*args)
    end
    def my_reader(*args)
        args.each do |method_name| 
            inst_variable_name = "@#{method_name}".to_sym
            define_method method_name do
                instance_variable_get inst_variable_name
            end
        end
    end

    def my_writer(*args)
        args.each do |method_name|
            inst_variable_name = "@#{method_name}".to_sym
            define_method "#{method_name}=" do |new_value|
                instance_variable_set inst_variable_name, new_value
            end
        end
    end
end
class TestMyAccessor 
     my_writer :a, :b, :c
     my_reader :a, :b, :c
    # my_accessor :a, :b, :c
end

o = TestMyAccessor.new 
puts o.a # nil
puts o.b # nil
puts o.c # nil
o.a = 2 

o.b = 3
o.c = "hello world"

puts o.a # 2
puts o.b # 3
puts o.c # hello world
```

***NB: I replaced attr_accessor with my_accessor, attr_reader with my_reader and attr_writer with my_writer***

Comment: Really nice. But you should make clear that this is just similar to what happens in reality. There are also differences in behavior, e.g. you cannot do `attr_reader :'x y'` whereas `my_reader :'x y'` "works" until the attribute gets accessed.